# How to protect my network?

Tags: wireless-networking

What are the best ways to protect my wifi network from any kind of attacks?

I have been careless about these topics and relayed on Windows Defender for the time being.But recently I got many malwares made me notice how lazy I was.

I need to know ways to keep my transfered data encrypted and protected as mush possible.

I heared about a lot of malwares able to infect one device and spread through the network, also about the ability to spy on networks even if they were secured .

I know that it's not possible to be 100% secured, but a high level of security is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can protect access to the *network*, to some extent, by using [WPA2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access). Some additional security is provided by MAC address filtering, but see [its limitations](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2052158/5-wi-fi-security-myths-you-must-abandon-now.html).
2. There are online security checks such as [Gibson's ShieldsUp](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2), which can give you some idea of router and PC vulnerability.
3. Use a firewall to protect each PC, whether that which came with Windows, or add-ons such as those suggested at [The Best Free Firewall Software of 2015](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/software/security-software/the-best-free-firewall-software-of-2015-stop-malware-before-it-gets-you-1284587).